# .htaccess rewriting url to a friendly format doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried so many codes from here and also googled a lot but none of them are working for me. I simply need to change `http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=5` to `http://www.domain.com/index.php/5`
I know this has been asked many times but all the code I try doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?index.php/([\d.a-zA-Z]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: @skrilled I just got the code from the net. I tried too many but none of them work.

Comment: If you really want a friendly url (neither of these two is...), you should aim for something like `http://www.domain.com/5/title-of-the-page`, see for example the url of your question.

Comment: @skrilled the www.index.php was a typo. it was actually www.website.com/index.php

Comment: @skrilled Okay so removing the `id` is impossible? for ex on gmail I see a url like inbox/1468793ed92f01ff and I am guessing they removed something similar to thi.

Comment: @skrilled [the htaccess file works just fine for me on files that exists](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IGvuq.png)

Comment: @skrilled "htaccess only works if the document in question does not exist." => I would be curious to hear where you ever read that.

Comment: what about `AcceptPathInfo`? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo